# How do I import .less files with string interpolation in the pathstring?

Tags: string, import, less, string-interpolation, dotless

How do I import .less files with string interpolation in the pathstring.

```
@folder: "LessFiles";
```

I tried this

```
@import "@{folder}/file.less";

Error:
File Not Found. 
HTTP GET Url is "%7Bfolder%7D/file.less"
```

and this:

```
@import formatString("{0}/file.less",@folder);

Error:
Server throws System.NullReferenceException
```

and this:

```
@path: "@{folder}/file.less";

@import @path;

Error:
directive block with unrecognised format on line 16 in file 'test.less':
 [15]: 
 [16]: @import @path;
       --------^
 [17]:
```

Any tips how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: it is an upcoming feature in less.js and dotless but requires a lot of work to implement.

Comment: Really? But it´s working for css attributes very well, e.g. its possible to define [background-image: url('@{image-folder}/loading-image.gif');], I´m wondering whats the difficult part.

Comment: imports are done at parsing and interpolation at evaluation.. need to get parsing to be allowed during evaluation.

Comment: issue on github (thanks to Luke for working on it): https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/249

Answer (score 1):

As of Less 1.4.0 variable interpolation is possible with `@imports`

**Example**

```
@bacon: "../bacon";

@import @{bacon}/smokey.less;
```

More information can be found here - [Less Language Features import statements](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements)